# Impossible to update expo project inside Expo Go after switching to EAS Build

Tags: react-native, expo, project, eas, expo-go

I have the need to run a project from Expo Go without being connected to PC. We are developing an app that require GPS and needs to be tested in open field.

Before EAS became the standard to create projects i used

```
expo build:android
```

ad this created not only the apk, but uploaded the project to my account and i was able to start it from Expo Go projects section just like the app was installed on phisical device. That worked also fo iOS and was a great testing feature.

After i moved to EAS Build

```
eas build -p android --profile preview --clear-cache
```

my project inside Expo Go does not update anymore and its stucked at sdk 44 even if now i'm working (and creating builds) with sdk 46.

I went through the official documentation many times but i don't get how to make the app start from Expo Go (project sction) as i did before. Maybe i'm missing some configuration.

Thank you all for any kind reply.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

I found the solution to this problem and now my builds are working and uploading to Expo Go.

Check out this information: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-build-archive.md

Basically EAS Updates will not bundle anything inside your .gitignore, in my case it needed specific config files. Did a quick test by taking them off the .gitignore and now it's working. Will move to GitHub SECRETS in the future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou very much, i'll dig deeper into this becaouse i've never used expo secrets. If that's working you just solved me a really big issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, Which files you removed from the git ignore?

Comment: Yeah so I had an API key and environment specific urls stored in a config file on my .gitignore. I just moved these values to GitHub secrets and inject them at build time. To be honest I am not 100% sure how secure this is, but for me it doesn't matter.